# What would be the impact of downvoting a question because you disagree with it?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, tactical-downvoting, downvoted-questions

It seems to me that when there is a topic that involves strong emotions, people will use the (down)vote to express their disagreement with the content of the question, regardless of whether the question is well-researched, clear, and useful*. For example, see [this discussion on Politics Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4681?noredirect=1).

<sub>I take "useful" here means "at least not *un*useful for the site, not unuseful for the voter. See [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252747/3416774)</sub>

So given that it is inescapable that people will downvote questions because they just don't like the content of it, I wonder what would be the impact of that? Is it harmful or are there even some good sides?

Comment: This is explained pretty well in this post on Stack Overflow's meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta

Comment: For me it is not even clear whether you are asking for this site, for the whole network or just meta sites....

Comment: I think OP is really asking about the question that that other meta question is discussing. This question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60345/if-the-justifications-for-informed-consent-are-questionable-then-why-would-it-b

Comment: That's just how meta site work. You vote for the content, not for its quality. Upvote means you agree, downvote means you disagree. It's that simple, and only when people take it personally and see it as "abuse", or "hunting them down", or in your case "tactical voting (!)", then it gets complicated. Because people can't grasp how simple and not personal it really is.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm asking for a general case. I've seen this on Workplace, Aviation, Infosec

Comment: @Shadow no, I'm asking for main site questions. That discussion on Politics Meta doesn't receive much downvotes

Answer (score 10):

What I see in the discussion on Politics Meta, is that the answer you got states clearly that your question *wasn't* well-researched, or clear:

> your quote doesn't actually present an argument against informed consent

You even suggest an edit or different way of asking your question in the comments there, suggesting you too realize the question is unclear.

> So given that it is inescapable that people will downvote questions because they just don't like the content of it, I wonder what would be the impact of that?

Standard system consequences apply. There's one other big impact of your statement: it spreads misinformation.

Wrong premises can be very unuseful to a site if they're mere misinformation. The idea that your question was downvoted because people disagreed with it is one such unuseful premise: It'll spread the idea that this is actually happening across SE. Other users will pick up on this line of thought.

Spreading of the idea that downvotes (outside of meta) are used to indicate disagreement will diminish the usefulness of downvotes as an indicator of a post lacking quality and usefullness.

As a consequence, people will just attribute downvotes to unwelcomeness and disagreement, see them as personal attacks instead of feedback on their content, and instead of improving their posts they will also spread these false premises further, reinforcing the misinformation.

Comment: I do not think it is so clear cut. *Some* people do downvote controversial questions when they do not agree with the premise. Downvoting is secret, and for free in the case of questions. How can you be so sure that it never happens? Sure, it happens seldom, but OP's question "What would be the impact of downvoting a question because you disagree with it?" is hypothetical (it uses "would"), and can definitely be answered.

Comment: (Minor comment) *the answer you got states clearly that your question wasn't well-researched, or clear* — wait. It's my intention to not include arguments against informed consent, because I only want to understand the quote taken from the source. The answer I got from Politics Meta gives me an impression that my question on Politics only has an ambiguous title, but the content is fine, and people only disagree the content.

Comment: @wimi I did not say it never happens, in fact I included a caveat for meta specifically where it happens a lot. Otherwise, standard system consequences apply. I've edited to include that.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. *The idea that your question was downvoted because people disagreed with it is one such unuseful premise: It'll spread the idea that this is actually happening across SE.* — is this sentence self-contradictory? For me the line of reasoning is this: (1) people downvote a question if it contains misinformation to stop it being spread; (2) This question on Meta SE contains a misinformation that (1) is correct; (3) therefore people do (1). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Regardless whether this happens frequently on the network or not (and I'm not saying that), the post in Politics Meta suggests that at least this happens frequently in Politics. Am I correct?